# Android FirebaseRecyclerAdapter for List of Objects

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

My firebase data structure is

```
{
"users": {
    "u1": [{
        "k1": "",
        "k2": "",
        "k3": ""
    }, {
        "k1": "",
        "k2": "",
        "k3": ""
    }],
    "u2": [{
        "k1": "",
        "k2": "",
        "k3": ""
    }, {
        "k1": "",
        "k2": "",
        "k3": ""
    }],
    "u3": [{
        "k1": "",
        "k2": "",
        "k3": ""
    }, {
        "k1": "",
        "k2": "",
        "k3": ""
    }]
}
}
```

I want to collect all values of key where key (u1,u2,u3) will be calculated in run time and can be more than 1.
Then I was using FirebaseRecycleAdapter to show this data.

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference1 = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("test/users");
firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FirebaseHeadlinesFeed, NewsHolder>(FirebaseHeadlinesFeed.class,
            R.layout.newslayout,
            NewsHolder.class,
            mFirebaseDatabaseReference1) {


        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(NewsHolder viewHolder, FirebaseHeadlinesFeed model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setNewsHolderFiled(model.getValues().get(0));

        }
```

Could some one help in this?

Comment: `NewsHolder` looks like what? You seems to have a list of users, not News... `R.layout.newslayout` layout? What is the exact problem here?

Comment: @cricket_007 Json Data Structure is only for representation purpose. My problem is basically I want to filter all data of users/u1 and users/u2 and show in FirebaseRecyclerView

Comment: The default implementation of FirebaseRecyclerView is to load all elements

Comment: @cricket_007 Right. So is there a way I can handle it while loading from firebase?

Comment: In my experience, you would need to implement your own RecyclerView, and filter the results from your Firebase callback to add to the adapter accordingly

Comment: Any link or pointer to refer?

Comment: I mean, just use a regular adapter and recyclerview. Add data like normal

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get all child(user), you need change this

.child("**test/users"); //**.child("users")**;

And your object **FirebaseHeadlinesFeed.class** need to be exactly same database with all attributes for retrieve data.

You can too, create queries for use in place this **mFirebaseDatabaseReference1**

example:
**var query = mFirebaseDatabaseReference1.orderByChild("k1");**